Utilize copy/move elision with a never again used reference
This has been bothering me for some time. Say we have a constructor that takes many parameters (copies or rvalues):
Object(A a, B b, C c, D d, ...);

When you need to use this constructor you can do it like this:
Object obj{{A params...}, {B params}, ...};

Which is great optimization-wise, since no copy and move constructors are called.
However, it can be hard to read at times. Also, perhaps A can be instantiated here but B and C will be passed as a copy. Therefore it makes sense to re-write it like this:
A a{A params...};
B b{B params...};
...
Object obj{a, b, ...}; // much nicer, but copy constructors are called

The problem is, with the latter approach, a copy constructor gets invoked for each parameter. This theoretically isn't a problem, since we can use std::move on temporary parameters:
A a{A params...};
B b{B params...};
...
Object obj{std::move(a), std::move(b), ...} // no copy!

But here, we get move constructors invoked.
Is there some way to enforce copy elision in such case - declare the variables but have the output like in the first case? It's seems like a super simple optimization compiler could do but even -O3 doesn't fix it.

EDIT:
After some trial and error I concluded this can be solved using template constructor with universal reference parameters:
#include <iostream>

struct A{
    A(){
        std::cout << "A - default\n";
    }
    
    A(A &&a){
        std::cout << "A - move\n";
    }
    
    A(A &a){
        std::cout << "A - copy\n";
    }
};

struct B{
    A a_;
    
    template <typename T>
    // Not sure if std::forward is needed here.
    explicit B(T &&a): a_(std::move(std::forward<T>(a))){
    }

    static B BCopyElision(){
        return B{A{}};
    }

    static B BCopy(){
        A a{};
        return B(std::move(a));
    }

    static B BMove(){
        A a{};
        return B{std::move(a)};
    }
    
};

int main()
{
    B::BCopyElision();
    // A - default;
    // A - move;
    
    B::BCopy();
    // A - default;
    // A - move;
    
    B::BMove();
    // A - default
    // A - move;

    return 0;
}

Is there a way to achieve this without (unnecessary) template constructors?

Fun fact, the compiler is allowed to do it so long as you can never prove that it did it, hence it will only work on trivial types, and if you ever try to figure out whether a move is happening or not then it will happen ..... such a case should be called schrodinger variables.

You could try declaring a bunch of lambdas auto a = [] { return A{params...}; }; and then Object obj{a(), b(), ...};. While this should cause no copy/moves (I guess), I'm not sure the optimizer can do a great job here.

@AhmedAEK That's interesting, guess I need to go into the assembly to figure it out? Also, do you have some sources on that?

@chi The idea is to make the code more readable, making such lambdas really achieves the opposite.

I can agree, but I can't see any other option. I'd also keep in mind that moves are usually very cheap operations. Removing unnecessary copies can be worthwhile, while removing moves... I'm not so sure. Unless you profile your code and observe that removing the moves has an actual impact, I'd keep the moves.

@tjzel you can just create two functions, and they both call the same third function, one will first create a trivial type on the stack while the other one will create it in the arguments, both will have the same assembly, if the type becomes non-trivial then they won't have the same assembly, compilers are allowed to do a lot of optimizations so long as you cannot prove they happened

I would suggest Object obj{A{A params...}, B{B params}, ...}; is slightly more readable and results in better compiler errors than the first option, and still has copy elision.

@JeffGarrett Yeah, but that's a minor tweak, those As and Bs would easily die if there were a lot of parameters for them.

@chi I don't actually mind the performance here that much. I'm just quite stunned that compilator doesn't optimize it straight off the bat.
